# Flask can't access cookies under @socketio.on when using with Eventlet

Tags: python, cookies, flask, eventlet

I am using Eventlet to do some background `emit` processes, but now ever since starting to use Eventlet, under every handler under `@socketio.on`, the `request` variable does not work as intended. For example, under an ordinary `@APP.route('/abc/')` I can use `request.cookies.get('csrf')`, etc. But under `@socketio.on`, `request` simply isn't the same. `request.cookies.get('...')` returns `None` every time.

```
import json
import os
import time
import eventlet
import gamble
import eng_puzzle
import authentication
import gcaptchacheck
from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for, request, render_template, make_response
from flask_compress import Compress
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, send, emit
from flask_sslify import SSLify
from store import REDISDB

eventlet.monkey_patch()
```

These are the imports.

```
def bg_emit():
    """Background emit"""
    currentpotinfo = json.loads(REDISDB.get('potinfo').decode('UTF-8'))
    pot_info = {
        'id': currentpotinfo['id'],
        'endtime': currentpotinfo['starttime'] + 30 - int(time.time()),
        'hashwin': currentpotinfo['hashwin'],
        'message': 'Entries closing in: ',
        'winner': 'Not yet chosen'
    }
    socketio.emit('infoupdate', {'info': pot_info}, broadcast=True)
```

Background emit function (above)

```
def testemit():
    """test"""
    while True:
        bg_emit()
        eventlet.sleep(1)
```

How it is called (above)

```
APP = Flask(__name__)
Compress(APP)
socketio = SocketIO(APP)
```

Defining `APP` and `socketio` (above)

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('RUN')
    eventlet.spawn(testemit)
    try:
        socketio.run(APP, port=80, debug=True)
    except PermissionError:
        HPORT = int(os.environ.get('PORT'))
        socketio.run(APP, port=HPORT, debug=False)
```

How the server is `run`. The `except` is just for deployment. (above)

```
@socketio.on('pot')
def handle_message(message):
    """Handle messages"""
    print(message)
    user = authentication.checksession(request)
    print('user', user)
    print(request.cookies.get('csrf'))
    if user and request.cookies.get('csrf') == message.get('csrf'):
```

One of the places that are having trouble. `authentication` is a custom script for authentication site wide. There are debug messages and they prove that `None` is returned every time a cookie is called. How can I get around this issue? Is there a solve to the issue itself or do I have to make my own way around it?

Comment: For the record, I just appended the auth cookie to the request body. Site uses https/hsts so it wasn't a problem (I think). Probably not the best solution though...